# Object reference not set to an instance of an object error though I am instantiationg the object

Tags: c#

```
  public partial class College
  {
    public CollegeDetails CollegeDetails;
    public List<Students> Students;
    public StaffDetails StaffDetails;
  }

 public partial class Students 
 {
    public StudentDetails StudentDetails ;
    public List<Marks> Marks;
 }
```

in my aspx.cs file

```
        College college = new College ();
    Students students= new Students (); 
    //List<Students> students = new List<Students>; 
     if (IsValidPost())
            {
                if (Session["xml"] == null)
                {
                    college.students.Add(new students{ });
                    Addtogrid();
                }
                else
                {
                    college = (College)(Session["xml"]);

                    if (college.students.Count == 0)----getting object refernce erro here
                    {
                        college.students.Add(new students{ });
                    }

                    Addtogrid();
                 }
            }
            else
            {
                if (Session["xml"] != null)
                {
                 }
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to need to do something similar to the following so that your types which are exposed by your composite types are not `null`:

```
public partial class College
{
    public College()
    {
        CollegeDetails = new CollegeDetails();
        Students = new List<Student>();
        StaffDetails = new StaffDetails();
    }
    public CollegeDetails CollegeDetails;
    public List<Students> Students;
    public StaffDetails StaffDetails;
}

public partial class Student
{
    public Student()
    {
        StudentDetails = new StudentDetails();
        Marks = new List<Mark>();
    }
    public StudentDetails StudentDetails ;
    public List<Marks> Marks;
}
```

A few notes on the above:

The constructor of a type is called just once, when the instance is created, which allows you to *make ready* for use, so to speak; in this case that entails instantiating your types that are expected to be used by an outside source (anything `public`).

I renamed `Students` to `Student` (non-plural), as a `List<Student>` achieves plurality by being accessible through a property named `Students`; I'd suspect you could do the same for `Mark/s`.

Comment: Good God! That's exactly what I wrote! Beat me by 2 minutes.

Comment: ...minds think alike (I'll omit the `great` modifier :).)

Answer (score 2):

You never instantiate the Student List inside the College class. Same goes for other objects in the College and Student classes.

```
public partial class College   
{ 
  public CollegeDetails collegeDetails;
  //Never instantiate
  //public List<Students> students;      
  //Should be:
  public List<Students> students = new List<Students>();

  public StaffDetails staffDetails;   
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add creation of `Students` and `Marks` to constructors.

```
public College()
{
   Students = new List<Students>();
}

public Students()
{
  Marks = new List<Marks>();
}
```

Or if constructors are unavailable then create those Lists before usage

Answer (score 2):

Just because you've declared an instance of College and Student does not mean you've created new instances of the containing objects. You need to create instances of them, too:

```
public partial class College {
  public College() {
    CollegeDetails = new CollegeDetails();
    Students = new List<Students>();
    StaffDetails = new StaffDetails();
  }
  public CollegeDetails CollegeDetails;
  public List<Students> Students;
  public StaffDetails StaffDetails;
}

public partial class Students {
  public Students() {
    StudentDetails = new StudentDetails();
    Marks = new List<Marks>();
  }
  public StudentDetails StudentDetails;
  public List<Marks> Marks;
}
```

BTW: Not a great choice of variable names.

Comment: +1 for the only answer without votes which addresses other obvious `null` issues.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like the constructor of the College object does not instantiate the Students list.